# Prefix inside Google geo chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I'm trying to get "$" next to amount. Should look like: "$0.005"
How to do that?

PS. `prefix: '$'` doesn't work.

```
  <script>
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Spent', 'Clicks'],
      ['US', 0.005, 1],
    ]);
    var options = {
      colorAxis: {
        colors: ['grey','#444']
      },
      prefix: '$'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: there is no such option available in api [doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks, but If you show me how to implement it in my code, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you read the documentation? It is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter) exactly how to achieve what you are asking for, with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use object notation to provide both the value (`v`) and formatted value (`f`)...

```
{v: 0.005, f: '$0.005'}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Spent', 'Clicks'],
    ['US', {v: 0.005, f: '$0.005'}, 1],
  ]);
  var options = {
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['grey','#444']
    },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

or use a number formatter to format the data table (which does the same as above)...

```
var formatTooltip = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: '$#,##0.000'
});
formatTooltip.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Spent', 'Clicks'],
    ['US', 0.005, 1],
  ]);
  var options = {
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['grey','#444']
    },
  };

  var formatTooltip = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '$#,##0.000'
  });
  formatTooltip.format(data, 1);

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: Great job. Thank you.